# Data layout in a ctypes Structure

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes

I am writing a ctypes Structure that holds two c_int16 variables, a real and an imaginary part. I feed this data into an outside module, and it is important that the upper 16 bits of this structure represent the real part, and the lower 16 bits represent the imaginary part. I declared my struct as such:

```
class sample(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("real" c_int16), ("imag", c_int16)]
```

The problem is that ctypes seems the reverse the memory layout, putting the imaginary part in the upper 16 bits and the real into lower 16. I have a temporary workaround by just reversing the declaration of the variables, but I don't want this as a permanent solution.

To verify that it is indeed ctypes/Python inverting the fields, I declared a Union structure:

```
class sampleUnion(Union):
    _fields_ = [("sample", sample),
                ("sample32", c_int32)]
```

I initialized a sample structure with some arbitrary values, and assigned the the 'sample' field with it:

```
x = sample()
x.real = 1
x.imag = 2
y = sampleUnion()
y.sample = x
print(hex(y.sample32))
```

Output is 0x20001, clearly showing that the imaginary part is in upper 16 bits...

I tried messing with the *pack* attribute, endianess, didn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *upper* and *lower* are not good terms, since they mean different things in *big endian* and *little endian* (*PC*) architectures.

Comment: "I have a temporary workaround by just reversing the declaration of the variables, but I don't want this as a permanent solution." - it's a solution, if you want visual order just assign them like you did in the example: first real, then imag. What else worries you?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem; if you try with `bytes(y)` you'll see that the underlying order is actually correct (`b'\x01\x00\x02\x00'`). The `hex` output will be "flipped" because you are on a little-endian architecture.

Comment: @Neitsa you were right. The problem was that the mentioned outside module would interpret the two 16 bit fields as a 32 bit field and because my architecture is little endian, the fields would appear to have been flipped. What I thought was a temporary workaround is actually the right way to do it; declare them in reverse order. Thanks!